# Windows FOR /F - Echo each line in file - Spaces in line - FAIL

Tags: windows, for-loop, command-line, cmd, spaces

I have a simple text file and would like to echo each line of the file.  This fails if the line has SPACES in it.

Here is the contents of the text file - " t.t "  Indented for clarity.

```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  a.a
  This Had Spaces
```

Here's the failing code :

```
FOR /F %G IN (t.t) DO (@echo %G)
1
2
3
4
5
a.a
This

FOR /F "usebackq" %G IN (t.t) DO (@echo %G)
1
2
3
4
5
a.a
This
```

Notes : This is not a batch file - but rather run directly at the WinXP command prompt - hence the % rather than %%

Comment: type t.t<br>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
a.a<br>
This Had Spaces<br>
<br><br>

FOR /F %G IN (t.t) DO (@echo %G)<br>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
a.a<br>
This<br>
<br><br>
FOR /F "usebackq" %G IN (t.t) DO (@echo %G)<br>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
a.a<br>
This<br>

Comment: Sorry trying to format better.

Comment: I did search b/f posting . . . answer is: http://forums.techguy.org/dos-other/807140-batch-files-read-strings-spaces.html    for /f "tokens=* %G in (t.t) do (@echo %G)

Comment: To change or add things to your question, make an edit, and not a bunch of comments. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %G IN ("t.t") DO (@echo %G)
```

By default `for /f` will tokenize the input records using spaces and tabs as delimiters. If you use an empty list of characters in the `delims` clause, this behaviour is disabled.